# How to Pickup Guns in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to add a pickup gun function in unity but it is giving me an error i am following this tutorial :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQoe2Oy78GU

here is my code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float distance = 10f;
    public float equipPosition;
    GameObject currentWeapon;

    bool canGrab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void CheckGrab()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward,out hit,distance))
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == "CanGrab")
            {
                Debug.Log("I can Grab it!");
                currentWeapon = hit.transform.gameObject;
                canGrab = true;
            }
            else
                canGrab = false;

        }
    }

    private void Pickup()
    {
        currentWeapon.transform.position = equipPosition.position;
        currentWeapon.transform.parent = equipPosition;
        currentWeapon.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 180f);
        currentWeapon.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;

        Debug.Log("Picked it up");
    }
}
```

and the error is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'float' does not contain a definition for 'position' and
> no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument
> of type 'float' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)   Assembly-CSharp E:\Unity\My
> Game\Assets\Scripts\PickupScript.cs   44  Active

the second error is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to
> 'UnityEngine.Transform'   Assembly-CSharp E:\Unity\My
> Game\Assets\Scripts\PickupScript.cs   45  Active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first error:
`equipPosition` is a float, which has no definition of `position` in it. `position` is available for a `Transform` type of object.

Your second:
`equipPosition` is a float and not a `Transform` objects, which means it cannot be used as a parent to an object.

You just need to change `equipPosition` to be a transform type of variable and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get a position out of a float.

```
public float equipPosition;
currentWeapon.transform.position = equipPosition.position;
```

you probably wanted a Transform.

Comment: can anyone tell why they voted -3 to me i can't ask more questions